# Multiplayer on Apple TV

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, apple-tv

I have a game for Apple TV that I want to make multiplayer so that people can use iPhones as a remote to play too. I am looking specifically on how to connect iOS devices to the tv so the tv can receive input from the iOS device. I cannot find anything on this. I'm not even sure what framework it would be or what it's called. Can someone point me in the right direction please, thank you!

Comment: nothing is built on iOS, you can use this guys library, https://github.com/robreuss/VirtualGameController, it seems to be the most powerful one that I know of.

Comment: I don't need a controller, I need to know how to connect it with the Apple TV so the Tv can receive input from iOS devices.

Comment: yes, nothing is built into iOS or Xcode, you need to use the link I sent you.  It does what you want (read the touch screen like a touch pad)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this before using Core Bluetooth, I found the documentation hard to read so I eventually shelved the project for another time, but here is the [apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html). I would start be making the apple TV a CBCentral, and using the Iphones as CBPeripherals. Good luck!